# Web GLSL parser in javascript

Tags: glsl, glsles

I am looking to parse GLSL 1 in Javascript. I searched online and there are a few available in other languages/

Does anyone know of a such parser written in JavaScript?

thanks

Comment: http://cimaron.net/projects/cwebgl/

Comment: Thank you very much Leushenko. That's exactly what i was looking for. Could you post the same thing as an answer please? thanks